# In Javascript how do I stop a triggered sound after it triggers again?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have this project and basically when I say 'up' it starts playing a song. But if it is triggered again tit wont stop but it will start the song again and because of that you get a mashup of audio.

```
{
  if (label === 'up') {
    console.log ('good fun');
    var vinden = Math.floor(Math.random() * nummers2.length);
    var denaam = nummers2[vinden]

    resultP.html('up' + '<br>' + '<br>' + 'Song: ' +  denaam.Titel + '<br>'+ '<br>'+ 'Artist: ' + denaam.Artist);
    

    
    play2Sound(denaam.Nummer);
  } 
else 
{
  console.log ('gestopt')
  
  //audio.pause();
  //audio.currentTime = 20;
}
```

If someone know what to do please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can play sound only if it's not playing

```
function isPlaying(audelem) { return !audelem.paused; }
```